# Configuring Ingress with a GraphQL Gateway + gRPC Microservices

Tags: go, kubernetes, graphql, microservices

I am looking to deploy a SaaS platform I have built on kubernetes but I have hit a barrier when it comes to setting up the deployment correctly. You can find the setup I am going for
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yehfR.png). I have tried setting up the ingress controller, and it is, in fact forwarding requests to the GraphQL gateway, the problem is that the GraphQL Gateway itself is uncapable of connecting to the other services due to gRPC connection errors. Below you will find my `Deployment.yml` which contains the graphql gateway, an ingress controller and one service called `general`

What I am asking basically is how can I connect my gRPC based services to the main GraphQL gateway

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: graphql-gateway
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: gateway
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: general-service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 600
  selector:
    app: general
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gateway
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: gateway
          image: myregistry/gateway:latest
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: general
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: general
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: general
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: general
          image: myregistry/general:latest
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 600
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/grpc-backend: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "playground.mydomain.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: graphql-gateway
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Comment: Looks like gRPC is HTTP/2 and kubernetes load balancing does not work well with it. There might be 2 problems here. It might be that services can't discover each other over gRPC this might be solved by checking if a proper CNI component is installed for your cluster. The other is that  you may require an extra network mesh to work with gRPC: https://linkerd.io/2.10/overview/#how-it-works

Comment: Thanks for replying, I was actually looking into linkerd but I have a question that I did not find a reply for. When installing linkerd in an already existing ingress controller how do you export a route for the linkerd dashboard?

Comment: @again One way is to add the annotation `linkerd.io/inject: enabled` to the Deployment resource and apply it. But you would need to re-create/restart any existing deployments. Because when a resource with such anotation is created, Linkerd should auto inject a tiny proxy sidecar to the pod and the service will connect to the service mesh.

Comment: So would you say this is enough? https://pastebin.com/inEGQbQN

Comment: What's the output of `kubectl describe general-service` ?

Comment: This is it: https://prnt.sc/11mr7vz @Christian

Comment: @agiann I would recommend following the official Linkerd guide to ensure you install the controllers in the cluster first and verify all required steps are done, then, use this anotation to add services to it.

Comment: And these are the 2 messages I am getting when trying to call the general-service through the gateway
https://prnt.sc/11mra98
https://prnt.sc/11mrbfd

Comment: I am using DigitalOcean as the kubernetes provider and they have an add-on for Linkerd, whenever I try to do "linkerd viz check" it gets stuck, but I might as well reset the cluster and do it manually

Comment: @agiann it looks like your deployments are expecting a connection via HTTPS/ :443 I am not sure where they are getting their certs from. Can you post the logs from the gateway that shows the connection to the deployment is failing?

Comment: @Christian, the 443 port is just one of the 2 ports I tried using either 80 or 443. Both of them had the same results. And the deployment never failed :(

Comment: What does `kubectl logs POD NAME` (you have to find the pod name for `graphql-gateway` show?

Comment: @S.D. Is there a tutorial/video/etc that I can see to understand how Linkerd is supposed to connect everything together? Not sure if my case is too special or not, it probably isn't, but this is my first time doing something so complicated :D

Comment: @Christian https://prnt.sc/11mt5kz

Comment: The IP address it is tying to call is different to the one listed in the service. You need to pass the IP address/dns name of the `general-service` to the gateway as an environment variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am not sure I am following :(

Comment: how is your graphql gateway configured to know where the other deployments are?